# Does read/write split have to be done on multiple machines?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to optimize mongodb using replica set and read/write splitting. Most people use multiple machines for replica set, however If all I need is read/write splitting, could I start more than one mongod instances on one machine and reach the same result?

Comment: DBA StackExchange would be more appropriate for non-programming questions. FYI: adding more `mongod` instances on the same server doesn't seem like an optimization as all those instances are going to be competing for the same physical resources. If the `mongod`s are part of a replica set each instance has to write the same data. Helpful background reading: [Can I use more replica nodes to scale?](http://askasya.com/post/canreplicashelpscaling). If you're interested in addressing performance I would suggest posting a question with specifics on your current metrics & concerns on DBA.SE.

Comment: @Stennie Sorry, didn't know there's a DBA StackExchange.

Comment: @Stennie There is a recurring notion that multiple `mongod` on the same server are supposed to be faster in writes than a single one. Since the limiting factor usually is disk I/O, as you surely know, this is simply wrong. I wish I knew where this idea comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple mongo instances on the same machine (for example the unit tests for the mongo drivers for various languages do this to test the driver against different topologies).

However if the point is to improve performance then you won't achieve much: you'll still have the same ram / io performance except now you've split them in 2. I suppose that there could be some gain due to each mongodb instance having its own set of locks if lock contention is an issue for you, but I would be surprised if that outweighed the disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

In general,  you can run all your mongo instances on a single machine using different ports.
I guess though that with the Mongo 3 new engine read/ write splitting will not be so needed.

Comment: Care to explain a little more on Mongo 3 new engine?